# Advice with implementing Java FXML MVC

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller

I'm using Java and JavaFX for the first time to make a basic inventory GUI application for a class project. I have a main menu and several submenus called from the main menu. I'm new to MVC, and I'm trying my best to keep my GUI control and logic separate. So far, I have my JavaFX start method setup like this(I realize the additional stage probably isn't necessary. It's just there to clarify that it's the main menu's stage):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage mainStage) {
    Stage mainMenuStage = mainStage;
    String fxmlFilename;

    fxmlFilename = "MainMenu/MainMenu.fxml";
    mainMenuStage = this.LoadFXML(fxmlFilename);
    mainMenuStage.show();
}
```

The main menu controller is then loaded and has the following code:

```
package c482.InventoryManagement.MainMenu;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import c482.InventoryManagement.C482InventoryManagement;
import c482.InventoryManagement.MainMenu.MainMenu;
import c482.InventoryManagement.MainMenu.AddPart.AddPartMenu;

public class MainMenuController {

    C482InventoryManagement loadFxml = new C482InventoryManagement();
    MainMenu mainMenu;
    Stage addPartMenuStage;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {    
        mainMenu = new MainMenu();
        addPartMenuStage = loadFxml.LoadFXML("MainMenu/AddPart/AddPartMenu.fxml");
    }

    @FXML
    private void partAddButton (Event event) {
        addPartMenuStage.show();
    }
```

The main menu controller instantiates MainMenu, which will have methods to handle any logic for the main menu's data. The controller also instantiates the submenu stages. The controller then shows the AddPartMenu stage when the appropriate button is clicked. From there, the AddPartController will instantiate the AddPart logic class and handle it.

Does this all adhere to the idea of MVC? Do I have the right idea? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: java naming conventions please!

Comment: Are you referring to the PartAddButton method? That was an oversight. I'm not sure of any other naming conventions I'm not following.

Comment: yes - and package names should be all lowecase letters :)

Comment: Okay, wasn't aware of the package names.